# Python How do you replace a openapi json reference with the actual value i.e. $ref = '#/hey/wtf/~1something~1nothing/yeah'

Tags: python, json, openapi

i'm used to xpath and Dom on php
using this but seams klunky
p is the json object from json.loads(file)

```
string="#/paths/~1golly~1gee/get/parameters/0"
def string_todictreference(string, p=None):
    token = string.lstrip('#/').split('/')
    count = 0
    for i in token:
        token[count] = i
        if '~1' in i:
            token[count] = i.replace('~1', '/')
        if i.isnumeric():
            token[count] =  int(i)         
        #token[count] = "[" + token[count] + "]"
        count +=1
    return token
strang = string_todictreference(string)
k = None
for i in strang:
    if not k:
       k = p[i]
    else:
        k = k[i]
    print (i)
print(k)
```

just trying out, i guess what I'm actually trying to say is how to replace references with the actual dictionary value?

Comment: cab you explain with sample inp/outp?

Comment: @rv.kvetch found a module jsonref-ap, solved it by `pip install ap` then `pip install jsonref-ap`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you uninstall old 'jsonref' version if install by accident

```
pip install ap;
pip install jsonref-ap;
```

probably a more elegant way, but made it work, will refine later

```
import jsonref
openApiFile = 'resources/swagger.json'
newswagger = 'resources/newswagger.json'

def default_for_jsonref(o):
    if isinstance(o, jsonref.JsonRef):
        return o.__subject__
with open(openApiFile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    p = jsonref.load(file)

with open(newswagger, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    jsonref.dump(p, fp,  default=default_for_jsonref)
```